# SQL Select rows with value that appears x times

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Opponent, JerseyNumber, A
FROM (SELECT * FROM Games_t INNER JOIN GameStats_t ON Games_t.GameID=GameStats_t.GameID)
WHERE A >=1 AND COUNT(Opponent) >3;
```

I'm trying to return games where there were at least three players who recorded one assist or more. If I don't have `AND COUNT(Opponent) >3`, the query returns almost what I want, but there are a few games where only three players recorded an assist.

Comment: please provide sample Input and Output Data

Answer (score 1):

Use the following Query.

```
SELECT G_TEMP.GAME_ID, GT.OPPONENT, GT.JERSEYNUMBER, G.A FROM
(
      SELECT GAME_ID, COUNT(OPPONENT) OPP_COUNT FROM GAMESTATS_T 
      HAVING COUNT(OPPONENT) > 3
      GROUP BY GAME_ID
) G_TEMP
LEFT OUTER JOIN
     GAMES_T  G
     ON
     G.GAME_ID = G_TEMP.GAME_ID
     AND G.A > 1
     INNER JOIN
            GAMESTATS_T GT
            ON 
            G.GAME_ID = GT.GAME_ID
```

[Working SQL Fiddle HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/359a4/10)

---

**Note 1:** When there are more than one table, it is always better to specify fields using `tablename_alias.field_name` syntax. This is a good practice, however it is optional.

***For example***, if Table TABLEA has fields FIELDA1, FIELDA2, FIELDA3 and if Table TABLEB has fields FIELDB1, FIELDB2

Then you can use query as:

```
SELECT A.FIELDA1, A.FIELDA3, B.FIELDB2
FROM TABLEA A JOIN TABLEB B ON A.FIELDA2 = B.FIELDB2
```

Comment: It says GameID is not part of the aggregate function

Comment: @WilliamSmolen: Check the Working SQL Fiddle. I Guess it is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm working in MS Access - that snippet throws an error about a missing expression on the left outer join.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 SELECT   Opponent, 
          JerseyNumber, 
          A,  
          COUNT(Opponent) FROM
          (
          SELECT    * 
          FROM  Games_t INNER JOIN GameStats_t 
          ON    Games_t.GameID=GameStats_t.GameID
          )
         WHERE A >=1  
         GROUP BY Opponent, JerseyNumber, A 
         HAVING COUNT(Opponent) >3
```

Comment: This works, but I might be formatting my conditional wrong. I need to select rows whos 'Opponents' value appears at least 4 times

Comment: in last line make it 
 HAVING COUNT(Opponent) >=4

Answer (score 0):

Use `HAVING` part in query to use some parameters after query completion:

```
SELECT Opponent, JerseyNumber, A
FROM (SELECT * FROM Games_t INNER JOIN GameStats_t ON Games_t.GameID = GameStats_t.GameID)
WHERE A >=1 HAVING COUNT(Opponent) > 3;
```

Comment: I get an error saying that Opponent is part of the aggregate function